# Check method calls on (private/ non exported) function made visible by rewire

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, module, jestjs, private

I have a module with only one exported function and a few non-exported ones to keep the api "clean". I'm trying to write unit tests using jest & require, but get the following error:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn())[.not].toBeCalledTimes()
    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received:
    function: [Function doMagic]
```

How can I get jest to spy on a non exported method that was made visible through [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) (or some other way to verify how often a method is called) if I try to spy I get this error despite being able to call the function in the last test as seen below: `Cannot spy the doMagic property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

**Simple example of my scenario:** 
eg.`functions.js`

```
const moreFunctions = require("./moreFunctions");

const theExportedFunction = someNumber => {
  return doMagic(someNumber);
};

function doMagic(someNumber) {
  if (someNumber % 2 === 0) {
    return moreFunctions.getTrue();
  }
  return moreFunctions.getFalse();
}

module.exports = { theExportedFunction };
```

**The other module:** `moreFunctions.js`

```
const moreFunctions = {
  getTrue: () => true,
  getFalse: () => false
};

module.exports = moreFunctions;
```

**How I'm trying to test it:** `functions.test.js`

```
const rewire = require("rewire");

const functions = rewire("./functions");
const moreFunctions = functions.__get__('moreFunctions');

const doMagic = functions.__get__('doMagic');

const getFalse = jest.spyOn(moreFunctions, 'getFalse');
const getTrue = jest.spyOn(moreFunctions, 'getTrue');

describe("testing inner functions ", () => {

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('theExportedFunction calls doMagic with 1 returns false and does not call getTrue', () => {
    const result = functions.theExportedFunction(1);
    console.log('result: ' + result);
    expect(result).toBe(false);

    //expect(doMagic).toBeCalledTimes(1);  // this blows up
    expect(getTrue).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    expect(getFalse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  test('theExportedFunction calls doMagic with 2 returns true and does not call getFalse', () => {
    const result = functions.theExportedFunction(2);
    console.log('result: ' + result);
    expect(result).toBe(true);

    //expect(doMagic).toBeCalledTimes(1); // this blows up
    expect(getTrue).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(getFalse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });

  // This works!
  test('just testing to see if i can call the doMagic function', () => {
    const result = doMagic(2);
    expect(result).toBe(true);

    expect(getTrue).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(getFalse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, you should be able to mock all and test `theExportedFunction` as follow:

```
const mockGetTrue = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true); // this name MUST start with mock prefix
const mockGetFalse = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false); // this name MUST start with mock prefix
jest.spyOn('my_more_functions_path', () => ({
  getTrue: mockGetTrue,
  getFalse: mockGetFalse
}));
// here import the file you are testing, after the mocks! 
// for example
import {theExportedFunction} from 'my_path';

describe('theExportedFunction', () => {
  it('should call getTrue of moreFunctions', () => {
    theExportedFunction(4);
    expect(mockGetTrue).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockGetFalse).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });


  it('should call getFalse of moreFunctions', () => {
    theExportedFunction(5);
    expect(mockGetFalse).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockGetTrue).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @quirimmo that's a slightly more elegant way of writing the tests. The issue I'm having thoughis in verifying: `expect(doMagic).toBeCalledTimes(1)` The line I commented out in the first two tests since I can't spy it.... but for some reason I can call it, as you can see in the last test.

Comment: in your case, the issue should go doing: `expect(moreFunctions.getTrue).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`. See, I am not using the variable, but direcly the method. When you mock in that way, the method is already mocked, you can spy on the method directly

Comment: Do you know of a way I can check the in-between method `doMagic` has been called preferably `toBeCalledWith()` or something similar so I can also verify the parameters? This is just a simple example to help me explain the issue